# nginx serving incorrect SSL certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate

I have multiple domains example.ink, example.wiki, example.app and example.dev They all run on the same VPS. However my .ink and .wiki sites are running fine but the .app and .dev notify that they use the .ink certificate.

My nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;


events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    # SSL Settings
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    resolver 127.0.0.1;

    # Point to Node App
    upstream example_node {
        server 127.0.0.1:3333;
        keepalive 8;
    }

    # Main site
    server {
        listen 80;

        server_name example.ink www.example.ink;

        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/sites/example_ink.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/sites/example_ink.key;
        
        server_name www.example.ink;

        return 301 https://example.ink$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/sites/example_ink.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/sites/example_ink.key;

        server_name example.ink;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/example_log.log;

        location / {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

            proxy_pass http://example_node/;
        }
    }

    # Wiki
    server {
        listen 80;
        
        server_name www.example.wiki example.wiki;

        return 301 https://example.wiki$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/sites/example_wiki.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/sites/example_wiki.key;
        
        server_name www.example.wiki;

        return 301 https://example.wiki$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/sites/example_wiki.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/sites/example_wiki.key;

        server_name example.wiki;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/example_log.log;

        location / {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

            proxy_pass http://example_node/;
        }
    }

    # App
    server {
        listen 80;
        
        server_name www.example.app example.app;

        return 301 https://example.app$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/sites/example_app.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/sites/example_app.key;
        
        server_name www.example.app;

        return 301 https://example.app$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/sites/example_app.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/sites/example_app.key;

        server_name example.app;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/example_log.log;

        location / {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

            proxy_pass http://example_node/;
        }
    }

    # Dev
    server {
        listen 80;
        
        server_name www.example.dev example.dev;

        return 301 https://example.app$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/sites/example_dev.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/sites/example_dev.key;
        
        server_name www.example.dev;

        return 301 https://example.app$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/sites/example_dev.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/sites/example_dev.key;

        server_name example.dev;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/example_log.log;

        location / {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

            proxy_pass http://example_node/;
        }
    }
}
```

My expected behavior:

```
http://example.ink redirect https://example.ink ✔
https://example.ink site loaded ✔

http://example.wiki redirect https://example.wiki ✔
https://example.wiki site loaded ✔

http://example.app redirect https://example.app ✔
https://example.app site loaded ✔

http://example.dev redirect https://example.dev ✔
https://example.dev site loaded ✔
```

Current behavior:

```
http://example.ink redirect https://example.ink ✔
https://example.ink site loaded ✔

http://example.wiki redirect https://example.wiki ✔
https://example.wiki site loaded ✔

http://example.app redirect https://example.app ✔
https://example.app site loaded ✗ [warning SSL of example.ink]

http://example.dev redirect https://example.dev ✔
https://example.dev site loaded ✗ [warning SSL of example.ink]
```

Comment: Are you sure that the used client application supports SNI? For multiple HTTPS services on one IP SNI is required.

Comment: As far that I can find I don't think that it SNI is supported on my VPS.
For clarification: I run Ubuntu 20.04 64bit. On there I use nginx for my certificates and point to my node application. I start my node app with pm2. My node app looks at the url with the vhost package and serves the corresponding application

Comment: I was not talking about https server (which is nginx) I was talking about the client you use for tests. This client has to support SNI.

Comment: Client is: Firefox 88 on Windows 10 and Chrome 90 on Windows 10

Comment: Please post the output of `nginx -T`

Comment: Issue was that I uploaded the `nginx.conf` to the incorrect folder. I noticed it by using `nginx -T` witch showed an older config at an other location that I have been using. Thanks!